Is there a name for this forward counting algorithm that produces prime numbers, even from some quadratic functions?
The algorithm is this

Start with an empty ordered set of prime numbers encountered
For each number attempt to completely factor it by all previously encountered primes, keep track of our reduced number
If no factors were found, our number is prime and add it to the end of our set
If factors were found, and our reduced number is not 1, then add it in order to our ordered set of prime numbers.

The interesting part is #4.
When our formula is num = x... ie first number is 1, second number is 2... etc...  The reduced number is always 1 and #4 doesnt do anything.
But if we do num = x^2 + 3x -1 we get:
1 3 is Prime {1}

2 9 factors 3 x 3 {1}

3 17 is Prime {2}

4 27 factors 3 x 3 x 3 {2}

5 39 factors 3 x 13 {3}

where at the 5th number 39, we were able to partially reduce it with our discovered primes before hand and 13 is a 'new' prime
The python code for the algorithm can be found here:
https://github.com/stanek/quadratitc_prime_generator/blob/master/main.py
I have left my computer running for half an hour on formula: x^2 + x - 1 and the program didn't generate any false primes.
There are also quadratic functions it doesn't appear to work for
If this is algorithm is true it is basically saying that any number encountered in #4 will not be a composite number.
I think this is really neat and if anyone can help point me into ways i might be able to prove this?  Is there even a way to write my algorithm in math language??
The interesting part is this seems to a be a shortcut through primes where you don't need to keep track of every single prime that might be out there.
Thanks for listening,  I am really excited about this and anything helps!

Your algorithm is not clear. Isn't an "empty ordered set of prime numbers encountered" a complicated name for an empty set? And if the set is initially empty, how to factor the first chosen number by all previously encountered primes, if there is none? What is "reduced number"?

In CS an empty set doesn't preserve order.  I specified ordered set since you can optimize the algorithm if the set is in order.
I tried to summarize the supplied code whilst trying to keep the algorithm in words simple.
if the set is empty, then the first number will be entered into the prime set (unless it is 1).  Thank you for pointing this out, this is a big part to not all quadratic functions will work with this algorithm, and something obvious that I didn't think of,
reduced number is the number you are left with after factoring out all primes in the prime set fully.
